# Enable a counter at a specific time everyday

Tags: vb.net

I setup a counter which needs to be enabled at specific time everyday. for an example lets say at (3 PM) everyday. what i came up with is following piece of code. but it gives me an error when it reach the time saying parameter is not valid please help me,

```
Private t As Integer = 0

 Private Sub Home_monitoring_tab_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        rs.FindAllControls(Me)
        Execute()
 End Sub

Private Sub Execute()
        If DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm") = "15:00" Then
            shift1_timer.Enabled = True
        End If
End Sub

Private Sub shift1_timer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles shift1_timer.Tick
        t += 1
        Label14.Text = CStr(t)
End Sub
```

Comment: You dont need to convert to string to evaluate the time.  Examine the `DateTime` properties and you will see there is an `Hour` and a `Minutes` property.  But that code ought not throw any error - but it wont do what you want.  The timer only gets enabled if you start the app at exactly 15:00.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour], and perhaps post the real code.

Comment: The `Execute()` method is being called once, only when you open the program so when you ope the program if the time isn't exactly `15:00`, it will not start the timer, so you can put the checking statement in another timer that is consistently running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, add a timer to your program and call it `CheckTimer` and update your code like this :

```
Private t As Integer = 0

Private Sub Home_monitoring_tab_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    rs.FindAllControls(Me)
    CheckTimer.Interval = 1
    CheckTimer.Start
End Sub

Private Sub CheckTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckTimer.Tick
    If DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm") = "15:00" Then
        shift1_timer.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub shift1_timer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles shift1_timer.Tick
    t += 1
    Label14.Text = CStr(t)
End Sub
```

**Hope it helped :)**